# How much time to give myself to change airlines on Changi Airport with and without baggage?

Tags: airports, singapore, jetstar, sin

I'm trying to book flights with multiple airlines to optimise the price, and I'm able to come up with a flight plan.

There's a specific connection that I am quite nervous with.

Leg 1 : 19:00 - 00:10(+1)
Leg 2 : 01:35 - 05:00

I'm not sure if 1:25 hours is enough to transfer from one airline to the next.

With and without baggage, how much time do you think I should have in Changi Airport to transfer to different airlines?

If it helps, first flight is with Jetstar, second flight is with Cebu Pacific.

Comment: I'd say this is largely feasible if your first flight is on time. And I think there lies the crux. Just look at [this flight](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/3k696/) for instance (I don't think it's yours, as the travel time doesn't add up, but it's same airline and same time of the day), this was late by around an hour or more 5 times out of the last 8 flights, I am not sure if that's a risk you want to take.

Comment: Awesome site. Wasn't aware of flightradar. This is [my flight](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/tz7/) and it seems fairly on-time, but still a scary risk to take. Would you want to make your comment an answer?

Comment: Well, I haven't technically answered the question, as one would have to find the transfer times etc., so I think I'll wait  for someone else to come along and answer it or maybe answer it later when I have time to find the details.

Answer (score 1):

Providing our inbound flight is on time then with no checked baggage, 1.25 hours is more than enough time.  You will need to change Terminal from T1 to T2, but Changi has an efficient and frequent air train.

Also note that Changi has individual security per gate, so as long as you can reach the security queue before the gate closes, you should be ok.

The only pre-requisite will be that you are able to obtain a valid boarding pass for your Cebu Pacific flight.  The Singaporeans are particularly picky when it comes to self check-in and often require self-printed boarding passes to be stamped by airline staff before they are valid for travel.  I would recommend contacting the airline for advice.

With checked baggage, you would really be cutting it fine and would need all the stars to align (on time inbound, speedy immigration clearance, swift delivery of baggage, seamless transfer to T2, no check-in queues) in order to be safely checked in 45 minutes before your departing flight.

Comment: "Providing our inbound flight is on time": that's an awfully big assumption though.  Since the OP proposes to do this with two completely separate tickets, they will be stuck in Singapore if the incoming flight is delayed.  Personally, I wouldn't attempt a connection like this without an overnight stay between them as buffer, but YMMV.

Comment: Everyone has their own tolerance for risk, and this is something that the OP will need to consider.  This particular risk can be mitigated by purchasing insurance (a late inbound flight is a perfectly valid cause for a missed departure claim), and "personally", I would have few qualms about attempting it.  Changi has a hotel and a swimming pool airside, plus numerous pay lounges where one can shower. I can think of many worse places to have to involuntarily spend a night.

Comment: The OP says they want to book this connection to minimize the cost, so they should understand that they are running a small but very real risk of having to pay a *lot* more than they saved to buy a walk-up fare to get to their destination.  Also, most (all?) travel insurance will require that you have a solid buffer *and* a "force majeure" reason for the delay (bad weather etc) before they will let you claim for a missed connection, eg. World Nomads has a 3-hr minimum.

Comment: I did not consider the *risk cost* of needing the flight to be on time. Thanks for bringing that up.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest giving yourself about 8-9 hours, maybe more.

This is what I did in the summer when I had a change at Changi.

The reason I suggest this is 1 you can relax and take your time and 2 this gives you plenty of time to go and be a tourist in Singapore :)

It's very easy to get from the airport to the centre on the metro system they have.